# String length function query in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to find all the documents in my collection for which the length of a certain field exceeds a certain limit. The field's type is string. Is there a function query that returns the length of a string field in Solr?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The solution is to use Solr's regex capabilities. For example, the following query retrieves all the documents for which the `title` field is at least 42:

```
title:/.{42}.*/
```

Comment: I have a document who's "description" field is 292 chars and 28 words (the largest description in the collection), but somehow when i query `description:/.{71}.*/` there are 0 results, and querying`description:/.{70}.*/` does return my document... what am I missing?

Comment: @joey, what is the type of the field?

Comment: org.apache.solr.schema.TextField

Comment: @snakile same issue here :/

Comment: Yeah this actually only works for very long words... so are any words greater then or equal too 42 chars. At least that is what I am seeing when I try too use this approach

Comment: for me this worked great, but only with indexed fields, not just mere stored fields.

Answer (score 2):

Querying by length is not supported out of the box, the most sensible way would be to create a separate (numeric) field and query by this field.

Comment: So I have to change my schema in order to do so? This is a one time thing that I need to do. Is the best way really to define a length field and then to throw it away?

Comment: If it's a one-off thing, you could [iterate over all documents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051460/solr-solrj-how-to-iterate-results-without-creating-a-giant-arraylist) and do the processing manually.

Comment: +1 because your solution works and is totally fine, but I think I've came up with an easier one. See my post.