# How to find all the documents in my collection in Solr, for which the length of a certain field is within a certain limit?

Tags: solr

I have to find all the documents where the size of a certain field, is within a certain limit, in fact within a range. Is there a way to do this Solr.
I have tried a lot of permutations and combinations, so any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use the method described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270571/string-length-function-query-in-solr . In your case, if you want to find out whether the size of a field is between *m* and *n* characters, you might use `myfield:/.{m,n}/`

Answer (score 0):

Which API are you using to communicate with Solr? I think you have a better chance of going around this on client side (ie on Solrj as a java regex filter function, or if its a web application communicating with solr through a http request this can be done through javascript). I would add this as a comment but I dont have enough rep.