# Kibana querying for string length

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is there a way to query for a value of a certain length in Kibana?

For example, given the following two KV pairs:

```
key: "some"
key: "something"
```

I would like to search for key.length > 5 and retrieve "something" only.

The other option I see is to add a tag from logstash, but then I'll have to reload a couple hundred GB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use script query to do that in **Kibana**. [Script Query in Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html), There is an example for script query with key's length more than 5:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "script": {
                    "script": "doc['key'].getValue().length() > 5"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also you need to **enable script search** in **elasticsearch**, you need to add the below config into **elasticsearch.yml**:

```
 script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
```

Comment: Thanks! Docs give the reason for enabling groovy search:
UPDATE: As a security precaution, starting with version 4.0.0-RC1, Kibana scripted fields default to Lucene Expressions, not Groovy... Lucene Expressions only support operations on numerical fields...

Comment: On my data date field was stored as a string can you tell me how to get substring and convert it into a date or explain to me how to query that data.
Field name: date
Stored as: Sat Jul 17 2021 19:03:30 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)

I want to filter by date. I want SQL Query if possible

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this with a regular expression query via the Lucene query syntax. For example `key:/.{6,}/` would only match records whose key field had an entry of 6 characters or more.

HT to a [similar question about Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23324965/600441) (which also uses Lucene's query engine).

Answer (score 4):

If you can reindex your index or you are just creating it, you can create a custom tokenizer as in the following:

```
PUT test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "character_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "character_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "character_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "person": {
      "properties": {
        "name": { 
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": { 
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "words_count": { 
              "type": "token_count",
              "analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "length": { 
              "type": "token_count",
              "analyzer": "character_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test_index/person/1
{
  "name": "John Smith"
}

PUT test_index/person/2
{
  "name": "Rachel Alice Williams"
}

GET test_index/person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name.length": 10
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a scripted field directly in Kibana.

- In Kibana, click on Settings tab and then click on your index pattern
- You should see 2 tabs "Fields" and "Scripted fields".
- Click on the "Scripted fields" tab. Then "Add scripted field".
- Enter a "Name" in the Script field and  enter the following:-

  doc['key'].value.length > 5
- Click "Create Field" at the bottom. Now your scripted field will be added & can be viewed from Discover page.

Comment: I don't know back then, but in 2019 it is: `doc['key'].value.length() > 5`. (`length` is a function and needs parenthesis)

Comment: Should I replace the `key` by the value I added in `New Scripted Field` ? or just keep `doc['key'].value.length > 5`