# search among best fields in elastic search with diffrenet size of search text

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose we have the query:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "brown fox",
      "type":       "best_fields",
      "fields":     [ "subject", "message" ],
      "tie_breaker": 0.3
    }
  }
}
```

which would be executed as:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": [
        { "match": { "subject": "brown fox" }},
        { "match": { "message": "brown fox" }}
      ],
      "tie_breaker": 0.3
    }
  }
}
```

suppose that the field "message" can be searchable if the text is only of length 5.

How can I perform the same logic that would be executed like:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": [
        { "match": { "subject": "brown fox" }},
        { "match": { "message": "brown" }}
      ],
      "tie_breaker": 0.3
    }
  }
}
```

The example is taken from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are trying to just do an exact match on the 'message' (since brown is 5 letters, you can read the following:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_finding_exact_values.html#_finding_exact_values

If you would like to do a match against whatever analyzer you'd like while checking the length, you can use an analyzer to do the string length and another to perform the match.

`

```
PUT ...index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "character_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "character_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "character_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "<object>": {
      "properties": {
        "message": { 
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": { 
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "length": { 
              "type": "token_count",
              "analyzer": "character_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`

Then you should be able to do a match with an and condition:

`

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": [
        { "match": { "subject": "brown fox" }},
        { "must" : [
           { "term" : { "message.length" : 5 }},
           { "term" : { "message.keyword" : "brown" }}
        ]}
      ],
      "tie_breaker": 0.3
    }
  }
}
```

`

Finally, you can also use scripting instead of adding another analyzer, as mentioned in this post:
[Kibana querying for string length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187269/kibana-querying-for-string-length)

`

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "script": {
                    "script": "doc['key'].getValue().length() > 5"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`