# how filter select result from lenght of filed in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

How can filter result of select query in solr with length of a filed
for example we want select all title filed in our core like below :

```
q=title:* 

q=title:* and lenght(*)>3
```

what we should do if want titles with length of 3 charachter of more , something like below

Comment: Use regular expressions, as mentioned in this question [String length function query in Solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270571/string-length-function-query-in-solr)

Comment: @CyprianoMenelucci greate idea , it's work